# how to multiply label data with an Int?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, floating-point, int

Im trying to be able to multiply the data in the label of price(1-3) by the counterValue to show the price for for each option that is selected

So far my code can multiply the **counterValue** by the **factor** of the selected optionBtn(1-3) when selected

What Im trying to do is multiply the counter value by the label data of the Price labels

All price labels are Floats I've tried using this code `Int(Float(modifyItems.cart.price1))` to replace the **factor** variable in the 'if statements' but still no success

SideNote: The data that populates the labels in the ModifyVC is passed from another VC. A delegate passes the data into the ModifyVC and the data is retrieved from cloud Firestore (as seen in the viewDidLoad)

thank in advanced for any help that is given

```
class ModifyViewController: UIViewController {

    private var counterValue = 1
    var lastSelectedWeightButton = RoundButton()
    var modifyItems: Cart!

    @IBOutlet weak var price1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var price3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weight3: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var lblQty: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var modifyTotal: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var option1: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var option2: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var option3: RoundButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        price1.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price1)!)"
        price2.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price2)!)"
        price3.text = "$\(formatter.string(for: modifyItems.cart.price3)!)"
        weight1.text = modifyItems.cart.weight1
        weight2.text = modifyItems.cart.weight2
        weight3.text = modifyItems.cart.weight3

    }

    @IBAction func minusQty(_ sender: AnyObject) {
         if(counterValue != 1){
            counterValue -= 1
         }
         self.lblQty.text = "\(counterValue)"
         var factor = 1
         if option1.isSelected {
            factor = 13
        } else if option2.isSelected {
            factor = 39
        } else if option3.isSelected {
            factor = 72
        }
        modifyTotal.text = "$\(factor * counterValue)"
        print("Decrease Quantity")
    }
}
```

---

```
class Cart {
    var cart: Items!

    init(cart: Items) {

        self.cart = cart
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just store the label data to (Int or Float).

```
var total = 0
if modifyTotal.text != " " {
  total = Int(modifyTotal.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "$", with: ""))!
}
let finalTotalValue = total + (factor * CounterValue)
modifyTotal.text = "$\(finalTotalValue)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  NSExpression to evaluate your expression like

```
let nExpression = "1 * 5"
let expression = NSExpression(format: nExpression)
var result = expression.expressionValue(with: nil, context: nil) as? Int
```